# An unexpected error has occurred

Tags: custom-masterpage

This error occure when I am trying to activate my feature but it will remove when refresh the page. Basically my feature do nothing only it will create custom master page and set as a default master page.

When I have try to get the details of error using error code then this message is display:

```
Message : Name=Request (GET:http://xxxxxx/_layouts/ManageFeatures.aspx
      ?Scope=Site)
Message : Site=/
Message : PortalSiteMapProvider was unable to fetch current node, request URL: 
      /_layouts/ManageFeatures.aspx, message: Specified method is not suppo
      rted., stack trace:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPChange.get_InternalL
      istId()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPChangeItem.get_ListId()     at 
      Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.CacheManager.HandleChanges(SPChangeCo
      llection changes)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.CacheManager
      .CheckForChanges(SPSite site)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.
      CacheManager.GetManager(SPSite site, Boolean useContextSite, Boolean 
      allowContextSiteOptimization)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.
      Navigation.PortalSiteMapProvider.get_ObjectFactory()     at Microsoft
      .SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.PortalSiteMapProvider.get_CurrentNo
      de()
Message : DelegateControl: Exception thrown while adding control 'Microsoft.Sha
      rePoint.Publishing.Navigation.PortalSiteMapDataSourceSwitch': Object 
      reference not set to an instance of an object.
Message : System.Web.HttpException: The DataSourceID of 'TopNavigationMenu' mus
      t be the ID of a control of type IHierarchicalDataSource.  A control 
      with ID 'topSiteMap' could not be found.    at System.Web.UI.WebContr
      ols.HierarchicalDataBoundControl.GetDataSource()     at System.Web.UI
      .WebControls.HierarchicalDataBoundControl.ConnectToHierarchicalDataSo
      urce()     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.HierarchicalDataBoundControl.
      OnLoad(EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     
      at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control
      .LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at 
      System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.Lo
      adRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at Sys
      tem.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPo
      int, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
 Message : Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (GET:http://xxxxxx/_layouts
      /ManageFeatures.aspx?Scope=Site)). Execution Time=11734.0497
```

How to solve this issue? I have also set RunWithElevatedPrivileges permission.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cb39b15e-c5e6-41f7-97c1-bfde32d9396a/error-portalsitemapprovider-was-unable-to-fetch-current-node?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious

Comment: I have tried the same steps form above link...but it will not work for me